# Can't pull DHCP lease with minimal Lubuntu install

Tags: lubuntu, dhcp

I have the minimal version of Lubuntu installed and I was able to connect to my ESSID via command line. I can confirm this via my router as I am seeing the mac address of my wireless card, but of course I am not seeing an IP address as of yet.

I then issue the [`dhclient`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/dhclient.8.html) INTERFACE command, and through logging I see many discover requests going out, but I am not seeing any response from my router.

I am using a basic Netgear Nighthawk router and DHCP definitely is working for all my other devices.

Any ideas what the issue may be?

As a side note, I also set a static IP using the `ifconfig` command setting the address, gateway, and netmask, but that doesn't seem to be showing in my router even though `ifconfig` shows a static ipset.

Really I'm just trying to get the network connectivity static or DHCP will work.

Edit: I also get a message that says

> no option named rfc3442-classless-static-routes in space dhcp

and

> ntp-servers: exception option name.

both in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

Edit:

I restored the dhclient.conf file to default and I am no longer receiving that error, but I am still only getting discover messages in my log and no response. When I use `dhclient` on the physical interface with a cable plugged in, I get DHCP immediately upon issuing the `dhclient` command. Whatever it is, it's specific to the Wifi.

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions. Look at `journalctl  _COMM=dhclient`. The sequence to expect is `DHCPDISCOVER`, `DHCPREQUEST`, `DHCPOFFER`, `DHCPACK`, `bound to ...`

Comment: How have you specified the SSID and WPA2 password? You will otherwise be refused connection by the access point.

Comment: @chili555 yes I diud specify and I am definitely connected as I see the wifi MAC from my router.

Comment: @waltinator thanks for responding. So I restored the dhclient.conf file to default and i am no longer receiving that error but I am still only getting discover messages in my log and no response. When I use dhclient on the phyical interface with a cable plugged in I get dhcp immediately upon issueing the dhclient command. Whatever it is, its specific to the wifi.